# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have been working on my project where I had to do some updates on my data records. After I finished my update I got an error: `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal` and this line of code was below that error in firebug : `maxScores.ew-19a = ''`

I looked up in my code and I found where is this output coming from, here is the code:

```
var maxScores = new Object;
<cfoutput query="getRec">maxScores.#LCase(tCode)# = '#maxScore#';</cfoutput>
```

In my update I had to put `-` symbol between letter and number, in old data I did not have that so I think that causing the problem here. I was wondering how I can prevent this or if there is any method that I have to put around my output to prevent this? If you know how this can be fixed pleas let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `ew-19a` is not a valid identifier, so you cannot use it in that form of object property reference. You'll have to quote it as a string and use `[ ]` to reference the property.

Comment: @Pointy can you provide example please? I have tried something similar but that did not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know ColdFusion but maybe `maxScores["#LCase(tCode)#"] = '#maxScore#';`

Comment: Simply use `maxScores[LCase(tCode)] = maxScore;` and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564218/when-and-when-not-to-use-hash-symbol-in-coldfusion).

Comment: Thank you @Pointy. I tried and works fine.

Comment: @Beginner Thank you! That helps.

Comment: @Beginner, you should write up an answer based on your recommendations

Comment: @Beginner - I'll be happy to remove my answer if you want to add one for credit.

Comment: @MarkAKruger It's fine. Thank You!

Comment: Your answer is actually simpler than mine anyway. I wasn't sure that would work without the evaluate operation and I didn't have time to test. :)

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion will attempt to subtract ew from 19a when you just dump it between to pound signs like that. You will need to use bracket/object notation here. Try this:

```
    <cfoutput query="getRec">
    maxScores.#LCase(getRec["tCode"][currentrow])# = '#getRec["maxScore"][currentrow]#';
</cfoutput>
```

If you want to Lower case something do it in the query. Outputing JS using CF is useful and solves many problems, but you want to keep it as clean as possible to keep your brain from fogging over. :)

Comment: `maxScores.#LCase(getRec["tCode"][currentrow])#` will again result the same. Also, no need for `[currentRow]`.

Comment: @beginner - didn't have time to test and couldn't remember if leaving out current row would work. :) - thanks!